# Flutter: Right overflowed by 200 pixels

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm testing Chips inside my Flutter App. 
I've added those chips inside Row.

But when no. of Chips increases, app shows yellow bar saying

> Right Overflowed by 200 pixels

I want to show only those chips which fits in 1st Row, All remaining chips should get displayed below to it.

My snippet:

```
class ChipsTesting extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips11')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips12')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips13')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips14')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips15')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips16')
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If by

> All remaining chips should get displayed below to it

you mean that the Chips should wrap when there's no space left on the row then you should use the `Wrap` widget ([Documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html)) instead of `Row`. It automatically displays its children in multiple horizontal or vertical runs:

```
new Wrap(
  spacing: 8.0, // gap between adjacent chips
  runSpacing: 4.0, // gap between lines
  direction: Axis.horizontal, // main axis (rows or columns)
  children: <Widget>[
    new Chip(
      label: new Text('Chips11')
    ),new Chip(
      label: new Text('Chips12')
    ),new Chip(
      label: new Text('Chips13')
    ),new Chip(
      label: new Text('Chips14')
    ),new Chip(
      label: new Text('Chips15')
    ),new Chip(
      label: new Text('Chips16')
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: what to do if one of those chip have long text suppose 5 line. How to manage that. I want to make every word visible by wrapping text tried updating maxLine property in Text but it do not work.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to wrap widget which overflows by `Flexible` widget, for e.g:

```
Flexible(child: Text())
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put your **chips** inside a **ListView** and add this line to **scroll horizontally**

> `direction : Axis.horizontal,`
> this error where the widget you created have more size than it' should

**Example**:you can't put widget on a **row** that will take **400 px** while your container got a

`width :200` =>that will give you an exception says =>Right overflowed by 200 pixels

```
class ChipsTesting extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
        child: new ListView(
         direction: Axis.horizontal,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips11')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips12')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips13')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips14')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips15')
            ),new Chip(
                label: new Text('Chips16')
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to leave an answer. However, it looks a little barren. Please update your answer to include a description/explanation of what you're doing :)

Comment: your answer is not useful, take a time to read carefully what exactly topicstarter wants

Comment: Answer is not applicable to the question.